# Is a Joint in URDF a frame in tf?

Tags: ros, urdf, ros-kinetic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!
I know this might sound silly but I just want to ask simple question to reassure myself. Is a joint in a URDF considered a frame in the TF library?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286758/is-a-joint-in-urdf-a-frame-in-tf?/) by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-03-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A `joint` in your urdf defines the transform between two `link`s, which are represented in your TF tree as frames.

So a revolute joint `joint_1` between `link_1` and `link_2` for which `JointState` messages are being published will cause `robot_state_publisher` (in this example) to update the relative pose of `link_2` wrt `link_1` based on the transform specified by the `origin` tag of `joint_1`. Rotation will be around the origin of `link_1` (plus or minus some offset specified by the `joint`).

> Is a joint in a URDF considered a frame in the TF library?

So I believe the answer would be "no, but `link`s are".

---

Edit: note that the `origin` element in your urdf specifies the transform between `link`s with the robot in it's *zero pose*. Afterwards those transforms are updated based on `JointState` messages.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on 2018-03-27**:
Oh! makes sense! Thank you so much!

Edit:

```
rosrun tf view_frames
```

confirms it